# What is the meaning of filter plugin RecordTransformerFilter uses filter_stream?

Tags: fluentd

err message:

```
fluent/event_router.rb:213:optimizable?: Filtering works with worse performance, because [Fluent::Plugin::RecordTransformerFilter] uses `#filter_stream` method.
```

I use `router.emit(tag, time, record)` in my plugin , and error occurs when I emit event,my conf section:

```
<filter info.type.abc>
@type record_transformer
renew_record 
keep_keys foolish,barsaker,idiots,similiar,
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore it.
We will fix this message at next release:

https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/pull/1227

Comment: but with this issue, my output plugin doesn't work ... I posted this issue on github, maybe u can help me :) https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/1246

Comment: 2023 is here. Still, do see that message for the `record_transformer`...